# Prevent an URL from being discovered

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Recently I've created a controller, which will do some insert into my database whenever I access the `url`.

My route config for it :

```
        routes.MapRoute(
        "SCRoute",
        "SC/{pdate}",
        new
        {
            controller = "SC",
            action = "Index",
            pdate = DateTime.Today.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
        });
```

My question is if I don't expose this `url`, will it be detected? Of course since there is no credential log-in, anyone with the link can access the page, **but if I can keep it for my self**, will it be safe?

There will be no internal links to this controller also. It won't be mentioned anywhere except in my mind and the route config!

Comment: Since the Routes are registered **once** (upon application start), the default value for your `pdate` parameter will always be the day when the application *started*.

Comment: @haim770 that's not what I'm asking

Comment: That's why i'm not answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but if I can keep it for my self

Its not safe, no matter how you hide it. You can accidently execute this URL or other developer can do that while understanding the code. Lots of things can take place to get it run.

If you want to insert something in DB, why don't you create a script and execute it. It would be a controlled change in any environment.

**UPDATE - After comment from user**

You can work out a solution on following lines:

1. Define an action filter.
2. Check for a unique value in the URL e.g. IP Address ([Example](http://randyburden.com/blog/2011/08/09/restrict-access-to-an-mvc-action-or-controller-by-ip-address-using-a-custom-action-filter/)) or write an algorithm to generate a hash.
3. When you want to run the action from anywhere, generate the hash and supply in the URL. The defined filter will verify the hash validity. A request with valid hash will only be served.

Hope this help.

Comment: I've written a service, which is now running on my server, but in case the server is down (power failure ...), I need some rapid method to insert the data, because my website content change on a daily basis. `Rapid method` here mean what I can easily access using a cellphone with a 3G connection